# Finding all the rows for n specific values in a column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

First off, apologies for my grammar (English is not my first language).

So I've been stuck on this particular problem and I have no idea how to solve it. I've tried searching on Google and Youtube and wherever else but can't seem to find anything that works. I couldn't find a question that had the same type of problem, but I apologize if this has been asked before, - I just couldn't find anything.

So I'm working with two tables. First I'm looking at the table

STUDENTS

```
PERSON_ID   ENROLL_PERIOD   PROGRAM_TYPE_LETTER PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME   STUDENT_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12401       109                 B               Bachelor            116901
15668       124                 B               Bachelor            147068
22671       132                 B               Bachelor            213071
22921       133                 B               Bachelor            215821
```

There are several other columns in that table but they're not relevant for the task so I didn't included them here (it's a rather large table).

As well as another table, **GRADES**:

```
PERSON_ID   GRADE   GRADE_DATE  GRADE_TYPE
-------------------------------------------
2308133      7      16-06-26        p         
2308133     10      18-01-24        p         
2308133      4      16-02-01        p         
2308133      7      15-06-29        p
```

(These are just a small piece of the tables). I need to find the grade data for the 100 students who are delayed the most and 100 students who are not delayed. A delayed student is a student that has been enrolled for 7 or more semesters on a bachelor and 5 or more semesters on a masters. The enroll period shows when the student was enrolled. So for example, enroll_period 138 means that the student was enrolled in the Fall semester of 2018. So 137 is the Spring semester of  2018, 136 is the Fall semester of 2017, 135= Spring semester of 2017 and so on.

So far I have been able to find the 100 most delayed students;

```
SELECT TOP 99 
    students.person_id, MIN(enroll_period) AS delayed 
FROM 
    students   
WHERE 
    enroll_period < '135' 
    AND program_type_letter = 'M' OR enroll_period < '133' 
    AND program_type_letter = 'b'  
GROUP BY 
    students.person_id 
ORDER BY 
    delayed
```

I also know how to join the table and get the three columns I want (person_id, enroll_period and grades), but I cannot figure out a way to find all the grade data for the 100 specific person_IDs. My problem is that in the students table each person_ID only appears once. So each row has a different person_ID. However in the grades table, each person_ID has many rows (for however many grades that particular student has).

I cannot seem to find a way that will give me those specific 100 person_IDs, while at the same time allowing them to be "given" several rows for all of their grades. I hope I make sense. I'm completely new to SQL Server so I've just been trying my way through this basically. I figured out how to join the two tables with a full outer join, but cannot find a way to pull all the rows for the 100 person_IDs that I want. As for now I've settled with doing it manually;

```
SELECT TOP 4774 
    students.person_id, students.enroll_period, grade 
FROM 
    grades
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    students ON grades.person_id = students.person_id
WHERE 
    enroll_period < '135' 
    AND program_type_letter = 'M' OR enroll_period < '133' 
    AND program_type_letter = 'b' 
ORDER BY 
    students.enroll_period
```

By manually I mean I found all the 4774 rows manually by looking at the 100 person_IDs that I found with the first code and just adding more and more rows to the SELECT TOP number until I reached the end of the rows for the last of the 100 person_IDs. I really hope I'm making sense here.

All the solutions I've found online only work for pulling out all the rows for one specific value (which is cool if I had to find like, 5 person_IDs, but not so much when I have to find 100), or if you need to pull out a 100 rows from, for example row 100 to row 200. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for a nested query like below - does that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a nested query like this:

```
select * from (
SELECT TOP 99 
    students.person_id, MIN(enroll_period) AS delayed 
FROM 
    students   
WHERE 
    enroll_period < '135' 
    AND program_type_letter = 'M' OR enroll_period < '133' 
    AND program_type_letter = 'b'  
GROUP BY 
    students.person_id )a
left join grades b on a.person_id=b.person_id
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great glad I could help!